# remove undefined value from object

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, key-value

I facing an issue in javascript, i want to remove undefined value from object

**Expected Output**
 Without `undefined` value ni array.

```js
var result = [
  undefined,  
  undefined,
  {
    group: '1042000018356',
    email: 'xyz@desk.com'
  },
  {
    group: '1042000098595',
    email: 'abc@desk.com'
  }
]

// This my logic:


result = result.map(function(index){

  for (var key in array) { // Looping
    if( index == key ){
      var group = array[key];  // Group id
      var email = key;         // Email
      return {group , email};
    }
  }
  
});
console.log("result", result);
```

How can i remove undefined value from Object

can anyone help me please?

Comment: `result ` is object or array?

Answer (score 3):

You can just do a filter and pass on a boolean constructor which will ensure you remove all the null and undefined values from the result array

```js
var result  = [
  undefined,  
  undefined,
  {
    group: '1042000018356',
    email: 'xyz@desk.com'
  },
  {
    group: '1042000098595',
    email: 'abc@desk.com'
  }
]

result = result.filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it with simple `filter()` to remove `undefined`, here the **filter** internally turns the return value of the callback to `Boolean` which is similar to `Boolean` constructor i.e `filter(Boolean)`

```js
result = [
  undefined,  
  undefined,
  {
    group: '1042000018356',
    email: 'xyz@desk.com'
  },
  {
    group: '1042000098595',
    email: 'abc@desk.com'
  }
]

result = result.filter(el=>el)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interest. Do you have some little explanation for (el=>el) ...Very clear approach.

Comment: @NikolaLukic **Edited** my answer sir with little bit of explanation :), thanks for pointing me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example :

```js
var newarray = [
  undefined,  
  undefined,
  {
    group: '1042000018356',
    email: 'xyz@desk.com'
  },
  {
    group: '1042000098595',
    email: 'abc@desk.com'
  }
];

var R = [];

newarray.map(function(item, index , myarray){

   // console.log("item -> ", item);
   if( typeof item === 'undefined') {
     // console.log("undefined detected!");
   } else {
     R.push(item);
   } 
 
});

console.log("result -> ", R);
```